# Problem getting codeigniter library for google reader to work when trying to log in and get feed data

Tags: codeigniter, google-reader

I'm trying to getting this http://www.forgottenexpanse.com/projects/ci_reader CodeIgniter library for interacting with Google Reader to work.

When following the examples on the page, this works fine:

```
$this->load->library('reader');
$shared_items = $this->reader->shared_items('12006118737470781753');

foreach ($shared_items['items'] as $entry) {
    echo $entry['title'];
}
```

But when trying to grab non-public data by loging in:

```
$this->load->library('reader');
$credentials = array('email' => 'me@gmail.com', 'password' => 'mypassword');
$this->reader->initialize($credentials);

$shared_items = $this->reader->shared_items();
foreach ($shared_items['items'] as $entry) {
    echo $entry['title'];
}
```

I get a bunch of warnings related to line 454 of libraries/Reader.php, like this one:

Message: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 128: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

I'm hoping someone has an idea what might be happening here.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you point to still uses the SID cookie to authenticate with Reader. That was [deprecated](http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi/browse_thread/thread/e331f37f7f126c00) a few months ago. The new preferred authentication schemes are either OAuth or ClientLogin with an authentication token; both are described at http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication.

In this particular case, you'll have to modify the `_login` function to get the `Auth` token out of the `ClientLogin` response. Once you have it, you'll also need to modify the `_fetch` function to include it as the `Authorization` header (instead of adding the cookie).

Comment: Thanks Mihai - that certainly shines light onto it.

Comment: Author of the code here: it was indeed using the old authentication method, the library is now updated to use the ClientLogin method provided by google.